# XML DTD error message: element type is required in the declaration of element type

Tags: validation, dtd, xml

I've searched Internet and this site, trying to find the answer to my question. Althoug I've found similar questions, the solutions suggested didn't resolve my problem.

So here it is. I'm working on an xml and associated DTD for class and when I check it in Exchanger XML Editor, I get the following error: "Ln 5 Col 37 - An element type is required in the declaration of element type "publication"."

Below is my DTD and XML document.

```
<!ELEMENT Bibliography      (document*)>
<!ELEMENT document          (author+, title, publication, media)>
<!ELEMENT author            (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title             (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publication       (#PCDATA,(city?|year?))>
<!ELEMENT city              (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year              (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT media             (#PCDATA)>



<Bibliography>
  <document>
    <author>Brennan, Niamh M., and John P. Conroy. </author>
    <title>"Executive Hubris: The Case of a Bank CEO. "</title>
    <publication>Accounting, Auditing and Accountability Journal 26.2 
    (<year>2013</year>): 175–95. </publication>
    <media> Print. </media>
  </document>
</Bibliography>
```

Thanks for looking at my quetion.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from a friend. It's quite simple really. XML won't process PCDATA and tags, so I modified the "publication" element from the first line to the second:

```
<!ELEMENT publication       (#PCDATA,(city?|year?))> 

<!ELEMENT publication       ANY>
```

Now it works.